# SQL : Alias in FROM subquery MySQL doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables : "discussion" and "message". I need to display only two discussions with the highest number of participants.

```
discussion
ID user title              timestamp
 1    1 First title topic  2016-02-20 14:22:15
 2    2 Second title topic 2016-02-21 18:03:55
 3    5 Third title topic  2016-02-23 16:00:28

message
ID discussion user message timestamp
 1          2    2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consect... 2016-02-20 14:22:15
 2          2    1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consect... 2016-02-21 18:03:55
 3          1    3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consect... 2016-02-23 16:00:28
 4          3    5 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consect... 2016-02-20 14:22:15
 5          2    5 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consect... 2016-02-21 18:03:55


SELECT d.ID AS idDisc FROM discussion AS d 
WHERE 1=1 
ORDER BY (
    SELECT (SUM(tmp.item)+1) FROM (
        SELECT (1) AS item FROM messages AS m WHERE m.discussion = idDisc GROUP BY m.user
    ) AS tmp
) DESC 
LIMIT 2
```

When I execute this SQL send me an error :

> 1054 - Unknown column 'idDisc' in 'where clause'

I have already tried many things, COUNT() does not work and gives me a completely wrong result. When I run the subquery by completing the ID directly in the query it doesn't work with COUNT :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM messages AS m WHERE m.discussion = '1' GROUP BY m.user
```

In the same way when I run the subquery that I wrote in my complete query and I write the values it works perfectly :

```
SELECT (SUM(tmp.item)+1) FROM (
    SELECT (1) AS item FROM messages AS m WHERE m.discussion = '1' GROUP BY m.user
) AS tmp
```

I think the problem comes from the alias that is not interpreted in the FROM of the subquery.

Please help me, I really found any solution...

Comment: Change your condition to WHERE m.discussion = d.ID

Comment: This question is asked boringly often. But your present query is nonsensical and  the title doesn't reflect the *actual* problem

Comment: You cant use an alias from a master query inside a subquery and not as a correlated subquery.

Comment: @sagi already tried, doesn't work...

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry but thank you to propose something in this case and put you in a more constructive logic. Thank you for your modification on my post about table structure...

Answer (score 0):

As @Strawberry points out, your query as written doesn't really correlate to the actual data you're apparently looking for.  To find the two discussions with the largest number of unique user ids posting messages, you would want something like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM discussion
 WHERE id IN (
    SELECT discussion
      FROM messages
     ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT user) DESC LIMIT 2
    );
```